# Swing Worker - Functions being called in their own order

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I'm trying to ensure the JFrame remains responsive while updating the GUI. I'm using SwingWorker for this. The scenario is during the sequential flow of the program the following code gets executed.

```
public int[][] readInputFile(MatrixOperations matrixOperations, 
        String inputFile, Boolean isDirected) throws IOException {
    List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(inputFile),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);        
    int[][] adjacencyMatrix = matrixOperations.createAdjacencyMatrixFromFile(
                            fileLines, isDirected);


        //The following two lines perform the computationally expensive operation.
        //So I'm asking SwingWorker to do this.
        task = new Task(fileLines, isDirected, ROOT_GRAPH);
        task.execute();


    return adjacencyMatrix;

}
```

This is the SwingWorker class that is getting executed. The problem I'm facing is during the execution of for-loop within doInBackground(). The three functions namely createNodeFromFile(source),           createNodeFromFile(destination),createEdgeFromFile(source, destination, isDirected) are being called in their own order during the execution of doInBackground() but they should be called sequentially. As a result I'm getting ConcurrentModification Exception or sometimes Node does not exist exception ( This is Graphstream library specific exception ). How do I resolve this?

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.graphstream.graph.Graph;

public class Task  extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer>{

List<String> list;
Boolean isDirected;
Graph graph;

public Task(List<String> list, Boolean isDirected, Graph graph){
    this.list = list;
    this.isDirected = isDirected;
    this.graph = graph;
}
@Override
public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.println(fileContent.get(i));
        if ((!list.get(i).startsWith("#"))
                && (list.get(i).length() > 1)) {
            count++;
            String[] arrLine = list.get(i).trim().split("\\s+");
            String source = arrLine[0].trim();
            String destination = arrLine[1].trim();

            createNodeFromFile(source);
            createNodeFromFile(destination);
            createEdgeFromFile(source, destination, isDirected);
        }
        if (count % 1000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Finished processing " + count + " lines");
        }
    }
    return null;
}



public void createNodeFromFile(String nodeId) {
    if (graph.getNode(nodeId) == null) {
        graph.addNode(nodeId);
        showLabelOnRootGraph(nodeId, nodeId);

    }
}

public void showLabelOnRootGraph(String nodeId, String label) {
     graph.getNode(nodeId).addAttribute("ui.label", label);
}

public void createEdgeFromFile(String source, String destination, Boolean isDirected) {
    if (graph.getNode(source).hasEdgeBetween(destination) == false) {
        graph.addEdge("S" + source + "D" + destination, source,
                destination, isDirected);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. Basically, we have to return the object Graph from Swing Worker. This object has to be then passed to process(). Here is the solution:

```
package main.graph.generate;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.graphstream.graph.Graph;
import org.graphstream.ui.view.Viewer;
import org.graphstream.ui.view.ViewerPipe;

public class Task  extends SwingWorker<Graph, Graph>{

List<String> list;
Boolean isDirected;
Graph graph;
ViewerPipe viewerPipe;

public Task(List<String> list, Boolean isDirected, Graph graph, ViewerPipe viewerPipe){
    this.list = list;
    this.isDirected = isDirected;
    this.graph = graph;
    this.viewerPipe = viewerPipe;
}

@Override
public Graph doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count = 0;
    //for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.println(fileContent.get(i));
    for(Iterator it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();){
        String line = (String) it.next();
        if ((!line.startsWith("#"))
                && (line.length() > 1)) {
            count++;
            String[] arrLine = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            String source = arrLine[0].trim();
            String destination = arrLine[1].trim();


            createNodeFromFile(source);
            createNodeFromFile(destination);
            createEdgeFromFile(source, destination, isDirected);
            publish(graph);
        }
        if (count % 1000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Finished processing " + count + " lines");
        }
    }





    return graph;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<Graph> graphs){     
    GraphGenerate.ROOT_GRAPH = graphs.get(graphs.size()-1);
    viewerPipe.addAttributeSink(GraphGenerate.ROOT_GRAPH);
    }

public void createNodeFromFile(String nodeId) {
    if (graph.getNode(nodeId) == null) {
        graph.addNode(nodeId);
        showLabelOnRootGraph(nodeId, nodeId);

    }
}

public void showLabelOnRootGraph(String nodeId, String label) {
     graph.getNode(nodeId).addAttribute("ui.label", label);
}

public void createEdgeFromFile(String source, String destination, Boolean isDirected) {
    if (graph.getNode(source).hasEdgeBetween(destination) == false) {
        graph.addEdge("S" + source + "D" + destination, source,
                destination, isDirected);
    }
}

}
```

Cheers!